# Opengl works in debugging mode but not when running

Tags: qt, opengl

I am creating a chess game using Qt and I use OpenGl to create my GUI. My problem is that when I run my program in debugging mode it works well but when I want to run it normally, it does not draw anything. Is it a dll problems? (btw I am NOT using glut)
this is the only library I add in my project:

`LIBS += -Opengl32.lib`

Comment: Have you looked at the debug output? Any error messages?

Comment: Yes, no errors at all. It even clears the screen to whatever color I want, it just doesn't draw objects! (using simple glBegin)

Comment: Why was this question closed?  If there was something wrong with it, it should be explained to the OP - this is not the way we welcome new users.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
LIBS += -L<path to .lib file> \
        -lOpengl32
```

Your `.pro` syntax is wrong.

Comment: I tried that too, it doesn't work!

Comment: In exactly the same way, or do you have different errors/behaviour?

Comment: Exactly the same, it seems it does not recognize library file at all!

Comment: Opengl32 is in a lib folder in my project path, does it make any problem?

Comment: The `Opengl32.dll` runtime should be in your system32 folder, so that is in on your path already.  I think the compile-time `.lib` path should be added to the `.pro` - see my update.